# Typescript: Instance of class type

Tags: typescript

I have the type of a class like here as `A_Type`?

```
class A {
  constructor(public a: string) {}
}

type A_Type = {new (a: string): A}
```

And Id like to get the type of the instance of the `A_Type` constructor, so that I could type this function explicitly

```
class A {
  constructor(public a: number) {}
}
//                                              ** not working **
function f<W extends { new(a: number): A }>(e: W): instanceof W {
  return new e(2)
}

let w = f(A)
```

I am basically searching for the reverse operation of `typeof` in typescript.

Comment: How do you intend to extend it? Pass other classes to f?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built in [`InstanceType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet) utility to do this

```
class A {
    constructor(public a: number) { }
}

// declare that the return value of the class constructor returns an instance of that class
function f<W extends { new(a: number): InstanceType<W> }>(e: W) {
    return new e(2) // return type is automatically inferred to be InstanceType<W>
}

let w = f(A) // w: A
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=21#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7rAPYDsIBcAnAV2Hy0IAoAHYgIxAEthowAuaHYgWzoFNCASkTQAvqnEpUAemnQAJn1BhCfaPgAWYfOo1rV%20YoRzQAbmBDE1WAGa61yqJlwESZCtANG8rE4zz4YDjA1naa2pjgUKg2xMH4jLjQNgA8AOrQfAAe%20Hw48jAInHwA7pTsnDz8QhwAkgFBIQAqAJ7UfOkAfGKdlHwcacLIaBhexsUlmZQATMKynnyG4-htaowwYMTk3NrMFiAt0P42Aqry6ljQ-ND1BI18re1dEqioIIvQkwC8yZSwc3IShxYEA)

Comment: `InstanceType<T>` does not work with `private constructor()` because it can not infer the `new () => R`. Is there a way to get a reverse operation of `typeof` with a class with`private constructor()`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function f<W extends { new(a: number): any }, R extends W extends { new(a: number): infer U } ? U : never>(e: W): R {
  return new e(2)
}
```

you need to use generics to extract the return type.

But if you always expect an instance of `A` you can simplify it to

```js
function f<W extends { new(a: number): A }>(e: W): A {
  return new e(2)
}
```

Comment: this infers w as `unknown`

Comment: true, fixed, please verify.

Comment: Upvote, indeed it works (no idea how though). Can you explain in few words?

Comment: `infer` extracts nested types, so it says `R` is `CONDITION ? VALUE_TRUE: VALUE_FALSE` and condition is `W` is a constructor, then we return `U` otherwise `never` what makes `R` to be `U`.

Comment: `A extends W extends {new (a: infer ARG): any} ? ARG : never` - now `A` is `number`.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html That's the info.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the following:

```
type Constructor<X> = {new (a: number): X}

function f<X>(e: Constructor<X>): X {
  return new e(2)
}

const w = f(A)
```